# How to program Firebase Cloud Functions to iterate through array of references?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm pretty new to Cloud Functions on Firebase and I'm struggling to program some code to iterate through an array of document references that have been downloaded from the Firestore.

The array is stored in my Firestore and contains references to each admin user in my users collection. Each of these users has a field in their document with their messaging token, which I need to send the message. I've manage to get the code to send a notification to a token that I define as a constant in the code however haven't had any luck sending to the tokens stored in the database.

Here is my code so far;

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

exports.notifyNewReport = functions.firestore
    .document('admin/reportsToReview')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        console.log('Change to doc function registered');
      // Get an object representing the document
      const newValueReports = change.after.data().reports;

      // ...or the previous value before this update
      const previousValueReports = change.before.data().reports;


      if (newValueReports.length > previousValueReports.length) {
        console.log('Report added to review list');

        var adminsArray = ""

        admin.firestore()
            .collection('admin')
            .doc('admins')
            .get()
            .then(doc => {
                adminsArray = doc.data().admins
                return console.log('Found admin UID: ' + adminsArray);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
                res.error(500);
            });


        //Code to get send notification to each device


        console.log("Construct the notification message.");
        var message = {
            notification: {
                body: 'There are new reports to review!',
            },
        token: token
        };

        admin.messaging().send(message)

      } 

    });
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Your code is completely ignoring all the promises from all the async work in your function.  With Cloud Functions, you have an obligate to return a promise that resolves only after all the other work is complete.  If you don't understand asynchronous programming with JavaScript promises, you're going to have a hard time with Cloud Functions.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Comment: You might also want to use this video series to get acclimated with Cloud Functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series

Comment: Hi Doug. Thanks for the reply. Sounds like a good idea to look at the basics first. I'll have a look into asynchronous programming for JavaScript! Thanks!